# How to use _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push in SharePoint without a time delay?

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SP2010 and need to run some javascript code to update an iframe when the page loads. Due to this, I have used the following method _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myfunction") to execute the javascript function. The problem is that the page loads (and the original html/css elements are loaded), then the page reloads with the newly updated javascript code. Any ideas on how to eliminate the delay? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://vimleshtiwari.blogspot.com/2010/08/alternative-of-using.html

He use a hack by calling the "onload" on a blank image instead of the function you mentioned above.